# Net force and external force of a system with internal forces

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, work

If $W_{net}=0$, then shouldn't $∆KE $ of the system be zero? It looks like opposite here:

[If net $F=0$ on a system then KE of the system may change due to internal forces or due to internal work done](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/591886/if-net-f-0-on-a-system-then-ke-of-the-system-may-change-due-to-internal-forces)

Is it because by saying $net F$ the op was asking only about external force ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If $W_{net}=0$, then shouldn't $∆KE $ of the system be zero?

Yes, but it is the $\Delta KE$ of the *center of mass* of the system.

> Is it because by saying $net F$ the op was asking only about external
> force ?

Essentially, yes. But again we are talking about $\Delta KE$ of the COM of the system for $\Delta KE$ to be zero.

To explain:

The underlying interrelated principles here are the the work energy theorem, conservation of energy, and conservation of momentum.

The work energy theorem states that the net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy. Note the phrase "done on an object". This means work done by forces external to the object. Moreover, the "change in kinetic energy" means a change in the macroscopic kinetic energy of the center of mass. When the net work done on the object is greater than zero, there is an increase in both the KE and momentum of its COM.

Consider the object as a system. The work energy theorem does not preclude the possibility of a change in the internal KE of a system ($\Delta KE\ne 0$) of its constituent parts, when the net work done on the system by external forces is zero, provided there is some potential energy (PE) in the system that can be converted to KE.

As an example, consider a bomb in outer space not experiencing any external forces (i.e., a bomb far from the influence of any gravitational field). Per the work energy theorem the change in kinetic energy of its center of mass is zero. Within the bomb, however, there is stored chemical potential. The bomb explodes.

Individual pieces of the bomb now fly off in various directions, each having experienced an increase in kinetic energy from when they were held together as one. The increase in kinetic energy of the constituents of the bomb comes from the stored chemical potential energy. Energy is conserved. Moreover, there is no change in motion (and therefore no change in KE) of the center of mass of the bomb, i.e. the velocity of the COM of all the pieces does not change.  Momentum is thus conserved.

So here we have an example of the net external work being zero, but having an increase in internal KE. The key, however, is that increase in internal KE has to be accompanied by some decrease in PE of the system for conservation of energy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a ton!!!

Answer (score 0):

Consider a bomb which explodes in mid-air:  The center of mass (and total momentum) continue to follow the parabolic path.  The total energy of the pieces will increase, but the changes in momentum average out to being equal and opposite.